# How to open a file from listview control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to open a file from a ListView control on a Windows Form project in C#.

I've created the ItemActivate event on the selected item of the ListView control and verified that it works properly by adding a MessageBox.Show().

I want to add to the ItemActivate event code to open the selected item if it is a file object.

```
// store current directory
string currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
private void browserListView_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedFile = browserListView.SelectedItems[0].Text;
    // the file exists open the file.
    if (File.Exists( Path.Combine( currentDir, selectedFile ) ) )
    {
        //
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show(currentDir + @"\" + selectedFile);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to add to the try block to replace the MessageBox.Show line in order to launch the selected file from my control?

Comment: What do you mean by "launch"?

Comment: `File.ReadAllText`  if you want to read it, `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` if you want to run it

Comment: I want the selected file to open in from the listview control like similar to the explorer window.  I believe I'm stumbled onto the answer in the documentation, right after asking the question though.  The `Systems.Diagnostics.Process.Start` method looks like it does what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path.Combine(currentDir, selectedFile));
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments, the Systems.Diagnostics.Process.Start is what I was looking for.

```
  private void browserListView_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     string selectedFile = browserListView.SelectedItems[0].Text;

     // If it's a file open it
     if (File.Exists( Path.Combine( currentDir, selectedFile ) ) )
     {
        //MessageBox.Show(currentDir + @"\" + selectedFile);
        try
        {
           System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(currentDir + @"\" + selectedFile);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
        }
     }
  }
```